# How to remove space between column headers and their below row in a HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I styled a HTML table like this

[image]

I want to remove space between table column headers and their below row. I tried various tricks but nothing worked. Please note that I am also using Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0.

I want to remove this red marked space without disturbing others.

[image]

My code:

```css
#tbstud {
  width:700px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:2px;
 }
  
 .column_heading {
  background-color:#d9e5f0;
  -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
 }
  
 .customer_row td {
  padding:15px;
  background-color:#f5f7f9;
 }
  
 .customer_row td:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #2585fe;
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px
 }
 
 .customer_row td:last-child {
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0
 }
  
 #tbstud .customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
  border-radius:0 0 5px 0
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />

<table id="tbstud">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th class="column_heading">Roll No.</th>
            <th class="column_heading">Name</th>
            <th class="column_heading">Class</th>
            <th class="column_heading">Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="customer_row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Sam</td>
            <td>MSc</td>
            <td>Delhi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="customer_row">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Amit</td>
            <td>BCA</td>
            <td>Mumbai</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="customer_row">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>103</td>
            <td>Rahul</td>
            <td>BCA</td>
            <td>Delhi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="customer_row">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>104</td>
            <td>Neha</td>
            <td>BA</td>
            <td>Pune</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="customer_row">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>105</td>
            <td>Pooja</td>
            <td>B.Tech.</td>
            <td>Chandigarh</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I still need gap between each row and each cell. But just need to remove this gap between very first row and below its row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this kind of hack:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />

<table id="tbstud">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr. No.</th>
      <th>
        <div class="column_heading">Roll No.</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="column_heading">Name</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="column_heading">Class</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="column_heading">Address</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>MSc</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Amit</td>
      <td>BCA</td>
      <td>Mumbai</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>BCA</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>104</td>
      <td>Neha</td>
      <td>BA</td>
      <td>Pune</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>105</td>
      <td>Pooja</td>
      <td>B.Tech.</td>
      <td>Chandigarh</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
#tbstud {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

.column_heading {
  background-color: #d9e5f0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.customer_row td {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}

.customer_row td:first-child {
  border-left: 3px solid #2585fe;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.customer_row td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#tbstud .customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/leo-melin/pen/rNaWxOq

So you just put the contents of  tags inside divs that have margin-bottom: -2px css in addition to normal heading style.

Also added `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags

Comment: I think this is the best solution among here. Others' solutions just cutting off border of headers when you zoom in enough to see the bug. I don't think we need `<thead>` and `<tbody>` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `border-spacing` and use table `border` property. You cannot restrict border-spacing for `tbody` only instead what we can do is remove the border-spacing property and use border property for the `table tr td`

```css
#tbstud {
   width:700px;
   margin:50px auto;
   border-collapse:separate;
   /* border-spacing:2px; */
}
/* Check Here*/
table tr td {
   border: 3px solid white;
   border-top: 0;
}

table tr th {
   border: 2px solid white;
   border-top: 0;
   border-bottom: 0;
}

.column_heading {
   background-color:#d9e5f0;
   -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
   border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
   color:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
   height:20px;
   line-height:20px;
   padding:10px;
   text-align:center;
}


.customer_row td {
   padding:15px;
   background-color:#f5f7f9;
}

.customer_row td:first-child {
   border-left:3px solid #2585fe;
   border-radius:5px 0 0 5px
}

.customer_row td:last-child {
   border-radius:0 5px 5px 0
}
   
#tbstud .customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
   border-radius:0 0 5px 0
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />
<table id="tbstud">
   <tr>
      <th>Sr. No.</th>
      <th class="column_heading">Roll No.</th>
      <th class="column_heading">Name</th>
      <th class="column_heading">Class</th>
      <th class="column_heading">Address</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Sam</td>
      <td>MSc</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Amit</td>
      <td>BCA</td>
      <td>Mumbai</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>BCA</td>
      <td>Delhi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>104</td>
      <td>Neha</td>
      <td>BA</td>
      <td>Pune</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="customer_row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>105</td>
      <td>Pooja</td>
      <td>B.Tech.</td>
      <td>Chandigarh</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-spacing` property on `#tbstud`

and add this css

```
.column_heading{
   border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.customer_row td {
   border-left: 1px solid #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removed border-spacing

no gap only after header

black color as example to be visible

```
#tbstud tr th{
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .customer_row td{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #tbstud tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  .customer_row:nth-child(2) td{
    border-top: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean then the solution would be to give the `.column_heading` a `position: relative;`, then add a `.column_heading:after` to add a line and the bottom of the `<th>` tag.

Try this

```
.column_heading:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #d9e5f0;
}
```

Don't forget to give the `.column_heading` a `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this property to 0

border-spacing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).